# How to generate object files in the build directory?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am currently working on a C project to implement a Linux userspace application.
I wrote this Makefile, which allows me to compile :

```
PROJ_DIR := ../
SRC_DIR := $(PROJ_DIR)/src
BUILD_DIR := $(PROJ_DIR)/build

# define the executable file
TARGET := tcp_proxy

# include paths list
INC_DIRS := $(SRC_DIR)
INC_DIRS += $(SRC_DIR)/rpmsg
INC_DIRS += $(SRC_DIR)/rpmsg/rx
INC_DIRS += $(SRC_DIR)/rpmsg/tx
INC_DIRS += $(SRC_DIR)/tcp
INC_DIRS += $(SRC_DIR)/tcp/rx
INC_DIRS += $(SRC_DIR)/tcp/tx

INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))

# source file list
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name *.c)

# object file list
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)

LDFLAGS := -pthread

all: tcp_proxy

tcp_proxy: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_FLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(TARGET)
```

However, the object files are generated in the same place as the source files.
So I would like to know how to duplicate the folders under "src" in a "build" directory and generate inside this directory the object files and the executable.

I would also like, when I do a make clean, to be able to delete all the object files and the executable.

My project :

[image]

Comment: There is no need to write a `%.o: %.c` rule.  make has default rules for common things like this; use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching would definitely find you a lot of examples and information on this.

First tell make what objects you want to build; change your setting of `OBJS` to this:

```
# object file list
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
```

Then tell make how to build it; change your pattern rule for building objects to this:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, it doesn't compile, I get "mkdir: missing operand"

Comment: It seems like you must have mistyped something, or else maybe your value of `OBJ_DIR` variable is something weird?  However, that's a very strange error message.  What version of Linux are you using?  You can try removing the `@` from `@mkdir` so you can see the command line to see what it says.

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
When I remove the `@` from `@mkdir` I only see the command `mkdir -p`. `@D` seems to be empty.

Comment: It's just not possible for the `@D` variable to be empty.  Make sets it to a value before it expands your recipe.  Please be sure you haven't typo'd something about the variable name, or added some kind of weird non-printing character, or something like that.  What is the value you set your `OBJ_DIR` variable to?  What is the value you set your `SRC_DIR` variable to?  You don't show these in your makefile.

Comment: Also, you can try adding the `--warn-undefined-variables` option when invoking make, and make will tell you if you've used the wrong variable name.

Comment: My bad. The rule lines I had copied just didn't have the right tabs in my editor, once that was fixed it worked perfectly! Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's a weird error to get for incorrect TABs; usually you'll get `missing separator` errors.  Make won't try to run the `mkdir` command at all if you have a missing TAB.  Maybe you tried to fix the `missing separator` error by adding `$(shell mkdir -p $(@D))`?  That would definitely give you the error you mentioned because `$(@D)` is empty outside of a recipe command line... in that case it would be better to report the actual error you get when running the command as suggested here, not an error you get from running a different command.  Glad you got it working!!  Cheers!